# catching errors from Postgresql to PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, error-handling

I want to catch and show the error(in a way that i choose) of a query on the web page using php . So instead of the code below

```
$result=pg_query($connection,$query);

if($result){
    //success

}
else{
    echo pg_last_error($connection);
}
```

can i use a method like error code matching or something else to achieve things like

```
if(error equals duplicate value error){
 echo "this value already exists";
}
else if(error equals different type error){
 echo "You should enter wrong type for column blabla"
}
```

Note I am using postgresql

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @AleksG
I don't want to use pg_last_error function . I want to write error message manually for corresponding error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's possible to retrieve the desirable standard [SQLSTATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) errcode, but there's a trick: the query has to be sent through the asynchronous [pg_send_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-send-query.php) instead of the synchronous `pg_query()`. This is because `pg_query()` returns `false` on error instead of the resource that is required to peek at the error details.

When [pg_get_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-get-result.php) is called after `pg_send_query`, it will block anyway until the query is done, so it does not really complicate things compared to the synchronous case.
And it returns a result which can be fully exploited for precise error handling.

Example:

```
if (pg_send_query($db, $query)) {
  $res=pg_get_result($db);
  if ($res) {
    $state = pg_result_error_field($res, PGSQL_DIAG_SQLSTATE);
    if ($state==0) {
      // success
    }
    else {
      // some error happened
      if ($state=="23505") { // unique_violation
        // process specific error
      }
      else {
       // process other errors
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Also, if the argument passed to `pg_query` might contain **several SQL statements** (separated by semicolons), the above example should be extended to retrieve all results in a loop, as mentioned in the comment by @user1760150. Compared to `pg_query` which returns only the last result, `pg_get_result` in a loop gives access to the results of each statement of the combined query.

Comment: It should be noted that this behavior does differ from pg_query when sending multiple sql statements at once. pg_query will have the results of the last sql statement, where as pg_get_result will return the result of each query in the order of execution.  If you want to perfectly mirror the behavior of pg_query, you need to add a while loop to capture the last result.

Answer (score 6):

You should parse the return of `pg_last_error` to know the type of error. So I would go to sth like this :

```
$result = pg_query($connection,$query);

if($result)
{
  //success
}
else
{
  $error = pg_last_error($connection);

  // you need to adapt this regex
  if (preg_match('/duplicate/i', $error))
  {
    echo "this value already exists";
  }
  // you need to adapt this regex
  elseif(preg_match('/different type/i', $error))
  {
    echo "You should enter wrong type for column blabla"
  }
  else
  {
    // different error
  }
}
```

Comment: Logical.But Isn't there more efficient or built-in way like if(errorcode==errorcodeof(duplicate_key) --> do sth

Comment: Well maybe, but have a look a [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.pg-last-error.php#99626) on php.net. The guy perform the `deadlock detected` by doing a `stripos` on the error. But I agree, if you can retrieve the code error directly, it could more efficient.

Comment: Yick. Is that safe in the face of I18N and translations? Can't you get the `SQLSTATE` from PHP and use that instead? That'd be the most correct thing to do.

Comment: @CraigRinger
 i couldn't find a way to get sqlstate from php for postgresql

Comment: Most of my data logic is done in stored functions in postgres. I do error checking there and raise exceptions if invalid data is detected.  With these exceptions, I define the codes myself.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* get access to SQLSTATE through the two main drivers.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error-field.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php