# How to get a specific part of pg_last_error

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to be able to return an exception, and php does it. However, php also returns the context for that particular exception, which I don't really like the front end user to see. Is there any way that I can just show the error part and not the context part of the exception?

```
        $query3 = "INSERT INTO sis.enrolledsubject (offeringno, regno) 
        VALUES ('$offering','$regno')";
        if (pg_query($query3)) {
          echo "New subject added successfully!";
        } else {
          echo pg_last_error($dbconn);
        }
```

The error is something like this:

```
ERROR: //My exception string here//
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function resolveconflict() line 44 at RAISE
```

I just want to show the error and not the context of the error. I tried something like `pg_result_error_field`but to no avail. I hope someone can help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: what error it shows ?

Comment: Something like this: `ERROR: //My exception string here//
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function resolveconflict() line 44 at RAISE`

I want to show just the error part and not the context part

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349230/catching-errors-from-postgresql-to-php

Comment: I'm not checking for an error, I'm checking if my Insert statement successfully went through after a trigger check.

Comment: Never use `pg_query` for query with parameters. Always use `pg_query_params` to be safe from SQL-injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
<?php

function error_exit($msg)
{
  fwrite(STDERR, "ERROR: $msg\n");
  exit(1);
}

$db = pg_connect("");
pg_query("create temporary table test(id int primary key)")
  or error_exit(pg_last_error($db));

foreach ( array_slice($argv, 1) as $arg ) {
  pg_send_query_params($db, "insert into test(id) values ($1)", [$arg])
    or error_exit(pg_last_error($db));
  $result = pg_get_result($db)
    or error_exit(pg_last_error($db));
  if ( pg_result_status($result) == PGSQL_FATAL_ERROR )
    error_exit(pg_result_error_field($result, PGSQL_DIAG_MESSAGE_PRIMARY));
}

?>
```

Try it:

```
$ php test.php 1 2 2
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_pkey"

$ php test.php 1 2 a
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "a"
```